# surjective polynomial map implies submersion?

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-geometry

Suppose $f \colon \mathbf{C}^n \to \mathbf{C}^m$ is a surjective polynomial map. Is it true that the derivative of $f$ must be of full rank at some point?

I know that the converse almost holds: If $f$ is a submersion at some point, then its image contains an open subset, and as $f$ is polynomial, its image is constructible, therefore it is Zariski dense.

I am also aware of plane filling curves $\mathbf{C} \to \mathbf{C}^2$ that are surjective and whose derivative is everywhere of rank $1$, but these are far from polynomial maps.

Comment: Do you know Sard's Theorem?

Comment: There are no differentiable plane filling curves.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes that is true. There are different ways to approach that:

1. In differential geometry, one learns about [Sard's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sard%27s_theorem). This states that the set of critical values of a sufficiently differentiable map $f: X \to Y$ of manifolds is a null set. The set of critical values is exactly the image of $\{x \in X: Df(x) \text{ doesn't have full rank}\}$. So if $f$ is surjective (or its image contains an open set), then there are always regular values.
2. In algebraic geometry over fields of characteristic $0$ there is a stronger version of Sard's theorem, which goes under the name "Generic Smoothness". A reference would be Hartshorne, *Algebraic Geometry*, III. Corollary 10.7:

> Let $f: X \to Y$ be a morphism of varieties over an algebraically closed field $k$ of characteristic $0$, and assume that $X$ is nonsingular. Then there is a nonempty open subset $V \subset Y$ such that $f: f^{-1}(V) \to V$ is smooth.

Here "smooth" refers to the algebro-geometric notion of [smoothness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smooth_morphism), which for $k = \mathbb C$ and $X,Y$ smooth means the same as submersion ($Df$ has full rank everywhere). Also note that "open" means Zariski open, i.e. the complement of a variety.

So in algebraic geometry the situation is stronger: The set of critical values of your surjective polynomial map $f: \mathbb C^n \to \mathbb C^m$ is not only a null-set, but actually contained in a Zariski closed subset.